# Ionic capacitor/filesystem - unable to delete file

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I have the following problem I am developing an audio recording app but when I use capacitor/filesystem it deletes the files created from the library but the audio files are not deleted and I get the following message Error:Unable to delete file

Answer (score 1):

few things to ask to help :
Which platform are you using : Android / iOS ? Because some setups are required for each to make the capacitor/filesystem API work.

Which folder are you trying to delete the files from ? If using Directory.Documents or Directory.ExternalStorage, this API requires the following permissions be added to your AndroidManifest.xml:

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Then, have you checked that the folder contained stuff doing something like "if folder.files[].length > 0" then delete ?

It might also be a bug linked to those files, I had this message once, cleared the files manually and since this everything been working fine.

Finally and if you haven't yet, check the readme of this API or the issues, you might find more clues. You could also had an issue about your problem : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor/filesystem

Comment: I am developing for android specifically version 11 of android and I have this message when I want to use the delete, I have set the permissions that you name me but it does not let me delete.